# In ASP.NET MVC project having same packages but different version at bundleconfig.cs and packages.config, which would be referred and why

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, packages.config

Like suppose in my packages.config file we have package tag referring to jQuery with version 1.10.2 where as in bundleconfig we have jQuery file which is of latest version.

Package from Which file would be referred and why

I did check under references of my project, there is no jQuery file
So would that mean even if I have package tag in the `packages.config` file, it won't have any effect.

Would it refer from bundleconfig only ?

Comment: In [tag:asp.net-mvc] the packages.config determines where nuget packages are included in the solution (.sln, .csproj etc) while bundleconfig determines what gets bundled in the js/css bundle.  They do not conflict with each other.  The packages.config has no impact on the output.  If you remove jquery from packages, but add jquery.js directly to your project and add it to the bundle, you'll get jquery.  If it's not in the bundle you won't get it.  bundleconfig => cs/jss  packages => nuget packages